# how can I access Session in preinit function in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie userInfo;
    userInfo = Request.Cookies["userInfo"];
    Session["EmpID"] = userInfo["EmpID"];
    Session["GroupID"] = userInfo["GroupID"];
    Session["DeptID"] = userInfo["DeptID"];
    Session["SecID"] = userInfo["SecID"];

    if (Session["GroupID"] =="1")
    {
        this.MasterPageFile = "master/hr_dept.Master";
    }
    else if (Session["GroupID"] == "2")
    {
        this.MasterPageFile = "master/hr_dept.Master";
    }
    else if (Session["GroupID"] == "3")
    {
        this.MasterPageFile = "master/hod_dept.Master";
    }
    else if (Session["GroupID"] == "4")
    {
        this.MasterPageFile = "master/default2_dept.Master";
    }
    else
    {
        this.MasterPageFile = "master/site.Master";
    }
}
```

I want to check my session value and then load the master page according to it, I am using same master page on the different pages.

Comment: It might be better in the case of null (non-existing cookie) to use a default value as in `string mything = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["mything"]) ? "defaultvalue" : Session["mything"];` then use that variable in your conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow your class to implement [IRequiresSessionState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate(v=vs.110).aspx)
such as:

```
public partial class YOUR_ASPX: System.Web.UI.Page , IRequiresSessionState
{
 // your preinit code

}
```

this is a flag interface which means not need to implement anything but allows you to access Session.