# Is there a way to set Master Page after reading query and session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables, master-pages

I was able to set Master Page programmatically in Page_PreInit like:

```
 Page.MasterPageFile = "Site.Master";
```

Since I can't read a session variable just set and change in every page load before or while this phase a code like the following didn't work to set different Master Page according to session variable which based on a URL query string:

```
 if (Session["PageLayout"] != null) {

     if (Session["PageLayout"].ToString() == "1") {
        Page.MasterPageFile = "FullWidth.Master";
     } else if (Session["PageLayout"].ToString() == "2") {
        Page.MasterPageFile = "SideBar.Master";
     } else {
        Page.MasterPageFile = "Site.Master";
     }
 }
```

Wonder how to set Page Master in ASP.NET C# based on session or query string passed on page load!

**Update:** I have tried using the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31636331/how-can-i-access-session-in-preinit-function-in-asp-net)
 but the problem is that in the other question the session generated while login and is used in another page while in my case the session value only available after visiting the page and based on the URL query / page ID or maybe I couldn't implement it the same way.

Comment: Where is your `if( Session["PageLayout"]` code located?

Comment: The following question may be useful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31636331/how-can-i-access-session-in-preinit-function-in-asp-net

Comment: in .ascx  control page load or OnInit @Dai

Comment: Seems it wont work for me or may be i don't know how to achieve it! The session value getting generated on load and written in page footer with the right value but the page master code which in Page_PreInit only applies after second refresh!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I access Session in preinit function in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31636331/how-can-i-access-session-in-preinit-function-in-asp-net)

Comment: no i don't thing it's the same case! @jcvegan .. I have updated why it's not in my opinion.